# Why I can't paste and copy from other program in Vim?

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I can't copy paste from other programs in Vim on my new Ubuntu 18.04 even I set up `.vimrc`:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

`"+p` or `"*p` is not working either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your Vim binary supports `+clipboard`, check output of `vim --version` or `:version` inside of Vim and check for that setting there.

```
$ vim --version | grep clipboard
```

Distributions often ship multiple versions of the Vim package, you'll want to install a more featureful one that is built with most features enabled and typically one that includes the GUI (gvim), since clipboard support on Linux requires X11 and that's typically bundled with the GUI version of Vim.

On Ubuntu 18.04, that's most likely the `vim-gtk3` package, use `sudo apt-get install vim-gtk3` or similar to install that package if you don't have it yet.

Also make sure the `vim` binary you get is the one coming from that package. (I believe you can use `sudo update-alternatives --config vim` to set that up. You can also use `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` to configure the default editor in your system.)

Finally, clipboard support needs to connect to X11, so make sure the `$DISPLAY` variable is set and set correctly when you start Vim. If you're starting Vim from a local terminal (gnome-terminal or xterm or rxvt or similar) that's typically the case... But if you're using something like tmux or screen and reconnecting to a session you might have opened outside of this GUI session, you might have a `$DISPLAY` that's out of sync... Update that variable to the correct value to fix that if necessary.

Comment: I used sudo apt-get install vim and I don't know it doesn't support clipboard. After installing vim-gtk3, It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The gnome terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>), i.e. the equivalent of `$ gnome-terminal &`
**does** support selecting text, copy & paste.

> This should not depend on vim, unless it is *evil* and turns it off somehow.

If you click the menu-bar you will find an Edit -menu, and there you will see that

Copy equals <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, and
Paste is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>

The <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> is there as *(legacy, traditional, since long)*;
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> stops software and
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> introduces entry of special character literals.

You may also drop file icons in the window and the filename(s) will be pasted (at the cursor).

Even more: Text selected in the shell window will be inserted at the cursor if you click the right side mouse button.

Additionally, as the terminal uses UTF-8 as default encoding of characters, you can do:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>2030<kbd>Enter</kbd> and see:

> $ echo "The value is 5 ‰ _

The codes for "all" characters can be found in `$  charmap &`

*Example: in charmap either search for 'ohm' (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>), or select `Greek` in the left list and find the ohm symbol, click on it and you see `U+03A9 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA` at the left lower corner of the window; now substitute `2030` above with `03A9` to see the omega sign in the shell.*